# Confused about backgroundworker not stopping when expected

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker

I have the following code. It is just a form app. On load it will run the bacground worker.

Then I have a button that is supposed to stop the infinite loop in the background worker by setting a flag to true.

I'm logging the out put of the `backgroundworker1.IsBusy` and it says it is busy but according to the logic in my code it shouldn't be busy because I set the flag to true thus exiting the while loop and running the `backgroundworker_Completed` event.

I must be doing something wrong but I can not figure it out.

If I'm approaching this incorrectly could somebody either help me fix what I'm doing wrong or point me in a better direction on how I can accomplish what I"m trying to do here.

```
private volatile bool StopScanning = false;

private void myForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
        {
            //do nothing
        }
        else
        {
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception boo)
    {
        Log.log(boo.ToString());
    }
}

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    while (StopScanning == false)
    {
        Application.DoEvents();
        try
        {
            ReturnScannedItems();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
        catch (Exception boo)
        {
            Log.log(boo.ToString());
        }
    }
}

private void cancelbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Log.log("Setting Stop Scan flag to true");
        StopScanning = true;
        Log.log(CloseScanSession().ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception boo)
    {
        Log.log("Setting Stop Scan flag to true");
        StopScanning = true;
        Log.log(CloseScanSession().ToString());
        Log.log(boo.ToString());
    }

    while (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
    {
        Log.log("Still busy");
    }
    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: Do not call `Application.DoEvents` on a background thread!

Comment: Originally i had it in the cancelbutton_Click method but I was searching and found somebody had it in the doWork. Neither made a difference

Comment: @Yarik: I'll go one further: do not call `Application.DoEvents()`, period. It is always a hack, to fix some design flaw in the code, and it's always better to just fix the design so that it's not needed at all.

Comment: Just a side note: Any "if `someCondition` then do nothing else do something" can be replaced with "If `not someCondition` then do something". Hence you should be using `if (!backgroundWorker1.IsBusy){backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();}` so you wouldn't need the `else` branch.

Answer (score 2):

You are blocking the UI thread, which prevents the `BackgroundWorker` from completing. It can't raise the `RunWorkerCompleted` event until the UI thread is free to process new messages (raising the event involves posting a message to the UI thread's message queue, so that the UI thread can then execute the code that will actually raise the event).

Your code also is flawed in that it's calling `Application.DoEvents()` from the worker thread. You should *never* call this method anyway, but it's particularly foolish to call it from a worker thread, because the whole point of having a worker thread is to avoid having to call that method (and it won't do anything when called on the worker thread anyway, because the worker thread shouldn't own any window objects that would need to receive a window message).

Instead of sitting in a busy loop, checking `IsBusy` and blocking the UI thread, you should just subscribe to the `RunWorkerCompleted` event and do whatever you need to do there. Without a good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that fully illustrates what you're actually trying to do, it's not possible to provide any more specific advice than that.

Comment: Thanks for the breakdown. I did have the Application.DoEvents() in the cancel method but now i know it is not supposed to be used. I was only checking the isBusy in the cancel method to see when it would not be busy since in theory at least in my mind it should not have been busy for an extensive amount of time after clicking the cancel button.If I place the Application.DoEvents() in the cancel it works.Its just that it takes a while for the it to perform the this.Close() and that is because for some reason it is still busy...its takes several seconds before it does the Close() function.

Comment: Without a good [mcve], there's not enough information to know why you see the delay. It's possible it's simply because of the busy loop, which has a tendency to eat CPU time and prevent other threads from executing, and that if you just included a call to `Thread.Sleep(1)` in the same loop, it would work better (but that's just as bad a hack as calling `Application.DoEvents()`). Or maybe there's something in the other code you haven't shared causing it.